# Bounded Context in Food Delivery Use case

Tags: domain-driven-design, object-oriented-analysis

I am practicing DDD with one of my projects , and this is my first interaction with DDD. I have a system which has 3 different kind of users , one is chef , one is delivery-man and on is general user . Chef is a concept who can advertise his recipes and takes orders . delivery-man is a user who signup and functions only to deliver food to respective addresses , and general-user is one who wants to order food .

From what I understand , these three kind of users belong to 3 different bounded context and not one such as 'User Management' OR 'Identity Management' . Can some one correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: IMO, this question is both too broad and opinion based.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to say without more information, but here are some pointers.

If you are thinking about CRUD "bounded contexts", such as "Users", "Chefs", "Deliverymen", those will be almost certainly wrong. Contexts are *not* CRUD services for an "entity", they are a semantically cohesive unit of features.

Here is a practical way to think about it: If two bounded contexts have messages flowing both ways, they are probably not good bounded contexts. Examples include: Get user/chef/delivery data (request-response), events flow both ways, or there is a synchronization in place both ways.

Here is another way to think about it: A bounded context should continue to work even if other bounded contexts are down. (It may get slowly out-of-date but it would continue to work).

**Some bounded contexts ideas**:

- Search
- Ordering
- Delivery

`Search` is for browsing restaurants/chefs whatever. Note that this thing does not need communication of any sort. Data will be pushed to it when necessary, but it would continue to work even if `Ordering` and `Delivery` are down.

`Ordering` contains some user data, like billing address, credit cards or whatever, but not all. It does not for example need delivery address. When ordering is complete, it would simply forward the user to `Delivery`. Note again, this would work even if `Search` or `Delivery` is down.

`Delivery` would have the user's delivery address and select the deliveryman, track the delivery. Note again: this would work even if `Search` or `Ordering` is down.

The cool thing is, these three would not need any direct communication at all. If all of them are web-based, they could simply link (redirect) the user to the next step, the user would never even see that these are potentially different applications.

This style actually has a name, it's called [Self-Contained Systems](https://scs-architecture.org/).

Comment: Thanks @Robert for such a detailed answer , let me provide more context to the problem space , so the project I am working on is a food delivery service , which facilitates the user in a way that he can search for chefs , order from chef is offering , chef accepts/rejects the order , if chef accepts it , then user who places order can track the progress of the food , once the food is ready , the delivery-man gets notification that ready for pickup to some address and payment is made via cash.

Comment: So , there will be three different kind of actors signing up to the platform , one who can cook food and we call them chef , one who want food , for them they are customers , delivery-man which facilitates that food is delivered to the right person .I was falling into trap that when designing services for their authentication/authorisation , it should fall into one Bounded Context (IdentityManagement) or three different bounded context (customer-account-management,chef-account-management,delivery-man-account-management) . As they are all users but reflect completely different concepts. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadSufyian something to think about, user management will be part of your solution however is it part of authentication really part of your problem domain? What I'm trying to say is you don't need to DDD all the things!

Comment: Robert, I agree with your answer, but I have my doubts that a service can do any meaningful work when the other services are down. For example, if search is down, ordering won't receive orders, because users can't find anything. If Delivery is down, ordering cannot receive orders because the checkout process requires Delivery accepting the delivery address and validating that the restaurant can deliver to that address. And so on. I do agree that the "already triggered processes" should be able to complete within a single service without needing the others.

Comment: Think about examples of still meaningful "partial" work: a user might have a pending order page, even with search down or delivery delayed (think XMas: you might want to order the last available special-offer item and get it delivered in a week, on the 25th; while Searching is hogged by too many users wanting the same rare offer). About the checkout process @Robert mentioned that address isn't an Ordering concern: we might add the option to takeaway. Imho, we aren't serving only a user with a single ideal workflow, and DDD bounded contexts help surviving to complex real world scenarios.